# How to remove target="_blank" from posts?

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a `Wordpress` Website. New posts redirect to an external link using

> target="_blank"

automatically. And I want it to be deleted from posts. I tried to modify **funcitons.php** but I still didn't find the appropiate code...

How can I achieve that?

Comment: WordPress doesn't add a target to links in posts by default. Must be a plugin or the theme.

Comment: Hummm it might be. I'm gonna search.

Comment: I stand corrected. There is a checkbox in the "add link" dialog. If you check it once it stays checked for new links until you uncheck it.

Comment: Do you mean in Post->All (my post)? Because I can't find this checkbox...

Comment: Edit/write a post.  Insert a link. There is a checkbox  in the dialog.

Comment: I see what you mean. But I don't want to add a new link. I want to modify the permalink to not open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the prettiest way, but this should do until you find code that adds target to external links

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'myfilter', 15);
add_filter('the_content', 'myfilter', 15);

function myfilter($content)
{
return preg_replace('#target=["\']?_blank["\']?#mi','',$content);
}
```